# Keep track of path in ftp

Tags: swift, ftp

How do I keep track of path or directory when i work in a FTP.
I use REBEKKA to access ftp, but there's maybe something better.

so the code simply list a specific path but how do I keep track on which directory I working in

```
session.list("/" + path)
```

Comment: ftp command `pwd` will tell you where you are. and since you're presumably building paths in your code, you should already know where you are/went to.

Comment: Never heard about pwd. And no I don't building a path. I just re-list everything so I should probably do something else

Comment: @MarcB how do you mean?

Comment: if you're doing programmatic ftp, presumably you have to do stuff like `cd('/some/path/'); put('localfilename', 'remotefilename'); cd('../otherdir'); etc...`. so you have to either know where you are because you're specifying paths to cd into, or you get find out where you are on the remote ftp server via the `pwd` command.